# Setting the axis custom limits matplotlib dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Across a list of dataframes (dflist), each showing some sensor readings in a 24 hour window, I am setting the y axis limits for these readings in matplotlib.

```
axes[3].set_ylim(dflist[day]['AS_%s_WE_%d(mv)' %(gas,sensor)].min(),dflist[day]['AS_%s_WE_%d(mv)' %(gas,sensor)].max())
```

So for each df in my list, a graph is produced. Unfortunately the first 10 minutes of readings throws of the scale dramatically, and I can't interpret the readings.

Now, for each df, instead of setting the minimum sensor reading as the ymin, could I tell the df to ignore the first 10 minutes (which is the first 10 readings, as I have 1 minute a reading) and take the min in the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean mask in pandas that filters out undesired values.
You didn't provide the structure of your dataframe, so I'm just writing something that gives you the right idea:

```
dflist[day[day['minute'] > 10]]['AS_%s_WE_%d(mv)' %(gas,sensor)].min()
```

Essentially you are indexing each row of day with a boolean value that is mapped to the dataframe using a conditional expression.